# Plotting histogram and dot-plot for participant reaction times?

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

[image]I have the following set of data, sampled here:

```
  X Participant   Group Event_Index         V
1    1           1 Control           1 11092.785
2    2           2 Control           1  1155.290
3    3           3 Control           1  1096.700
4    4           4 Control           1  2137.435
5    5           5 Control           1  1199.000
6    6           6 Control           1   925.550
7    7           7 Control           1  1885.180
8    8           8 Control           1   882.800
9    9           9 Control           1  4834.785
10  10          10 Control           1  2071.815
11  11          11 Control           1  4561.000
12  12          12 Control           1  2235.150
13  13          13 Control           1  2386.525
14  14          14 Control           1  4556.000
15  15          15 Control           1  2016.225
16  16          16 Control           1  1776.595
17  17          17 Control           1  5417.160
18  18          18 Control           1  2224.470
```

Reaction times for n=18 participants over 90 trials in a sample. I'd like to make a histogram and dot-plot to visualize the distribution of reaction times. When I use the following code, I am having trouble editing the axis.

```
hist(control_RT$V,xlim=(0,50000))
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'trouble editing the axis'

Comment: it appears as seen above... when I use the xlim function I receive the following error: Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : invalid 'xlim' value

Comment: OK. Can you edit your question to show us the exact command you used - at the moment there is no ``xlim`` call in your example

Comment: @user438383 I've edited, sorry!!

Comment: Thanks. Just add a ``c`` before the to the brackets, so it's ``hist(control_RT$V, xlim = c(0,50000))`` and it should work.

Comment: thank you @user438383, the visual is still not great for the data because the axis intervals are too large. How do you index at smaller intervals?